# Erro ao comparar senha MD5 em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, login, md5

Estou com um problema em um form de login, abaixo segue os códigos atuais.

Estou utilizando o método via POST, o que ocorre é que ele não esta enviando o post em MD5 para que seja feita a comparação no DB.

No banco de dados já esta registrado a senha em MD5, porém ao enviar os dados por esse form para ele concluir o login ele não converte a senha.

Alguém sabe onde esta o erro?

**form login**

```
<form id="1" name="1" action="pass.php" method="post">
   <div class="login">
      <input placeholder="Usuário" type="text" id="username" size="25" name="name" /><br>
      <input placeholder="Senha" id="pass" type="password" size="25" name="pass" /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="_2" value="Login" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="ed_type" value="" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<? echo $redirect;?>" />
   </div>
</form>
```

**pass.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();
$usuario_admin = isset($_SESSION['1x11']) ? $_SESSION['1x11'] : '';

include("conf.inc.php");
include("conectar.php");

$query = "select * from admin where username='" . $_POST["name"] . "' and pass=MD5('" . $_POST["pass"] . "')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$ADMIN_USERNAME = $row["username"];
$ADMIN_PASSWORD = $row["pass"];

if ($total > 0) {
    if ($name == $ADMIN_USERNAME && $pass == $ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
        if ($usuario_admin != '')
            $_SESSION['1x11'] = "";
        $_SESSION["1x11"] = $name;
        $_SESSION['logedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION["type"] = $row["type"];
        $_SESSION["usrname"] = $name;
        $_SESSION["logid"] = $row["id"];
        header("Location:index2.php");
    }
} else {
    header("Location:index.php?id=1");
}
?>
```

**Informações do post enviado utilizando TAMPER DATA:**

```
Host=dominio.com
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language=pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
Referer=http://dominio.com/admin/index.php?id=1
Cookie=PHPSESSID=1d5d5r8hlp6hnebv9pa115d8r
Connection=keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=1
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length=59
POSTDATA=name=admin&pass=admin&_2=Login&ed_type=&redirect=
```

**NOVO ERRO:**

```
Notice: date_default_timezone_set() [function.date-default-timezone-set]: Timezone ID '-03:00' is invalid in /home/user/public_html/admin/adm.config.inc.php on line 15

Notice: date_default_timezone_set() [function.date-default-timezone-set]: Timezone ID '-03:00' is invalid in /home/user/public_html/admin/conf.inc.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: timezone_set in /home/user/public_html/admin/conectar.php on line 9

Notice: Use of undefined constant hora - assumed 'hora' in /home/user/public_html/admin/conectar.php on line 14
```

**conectar.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("conf.inc.php");


    $db=mysql_connect($DBSERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
    if (!$db) die('N&atilde;o foi possivel conectar: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($DATABASENAME,$db);

    if ($timezone_set=="")$timezone_set="America/Sao_Paulo";
    $sql = mysql_query("Set @@global.timezone = '".$timezone_set."';");

    $sql = mysql_query("Select Now() as hora");
    $dados=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $Hora_Servidor_MySQL = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($dados[hora]));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

seu erro esta na sua query

a correta deveria ser

```
$query = "select * from admin where username='" . $_POST["name"] . "' and pass='" . MD5($_POST["pass"]) . "'";
```

Comment: Já tinha tentado dessa forma e ele não funciona de jeito nenhum... :(

Comment: faz um favor, vc esta passando para o seu sistema a senha admin , copia la no seu db como ela esta e posta aqui. ( o hash md5 dela )

Comment: Segue: `21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801f`

Comment: ta ai seu problema o md5 de admin é 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 provavelmente seu campo no mysql d senha esta limitado aumente o varchar para 50 q resolve

Comment: Nossa realmente, que mancada! rsrs

Mas agora deu outro problema, ele fica com a tela em branco quando loga. Redireciona para pass.php e fica a tela branca.

Comment: rss agora é outro problema vc tem q revisar seu script. habilita a exibição de erros do php e posta o erro.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, pode dar uma olhada? Estranho esses erros por que se eu não usar MD5 ele faz o login normalmente, e usando MD5 ocorre esses erros. Por que será?

Comment: da onde vc recebe o $dados[hora]? e sobre o default time zone leia isto http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: seria algo assim date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

Comment: Já corrigir nesses dois aquivos, agora só ficou o erro no arquivo conectar.php, atualizei a pergunta com o código completo desse arquivo... Na verdade esses $dados[hora] não sei da onde recebe, pois naõ tem nenhuma referência nos arquivos, nem no conectar nem no conf.inc, estranho...

Comment: entao deveria ser assim $Hora_Servidor_MySQL = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

Comment: Ta complicado fazer funcionar, sumiu todos os erros porém ainda fica com a tela branca e não redireciona para a página inicial.

Comment: faz um redirecionamento por meta e nao por header pois vc pode ta tendo algum output anets dessa header echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;index2.php'>";

Comment: Não funcionou também, continua tela branca. oO

Comment: estranho m add no skype eu t ajudo por teamviewer -> jasaroc